# Is community college GPA not included as the net GPA on the resume?

Tags: grades, gpa, transfer-student, community-college

I am a student in the US who is going to graduate with my bachelor's degree and I want to start applying for jobs. I am not sure if what GPA should I provide for job applications on my CV. I studied first 4 semester in a community college with a GPA of 3.8 and then got transfer to a university for the remaining 4 semesters. On transfer, my GPA was not carried over. I had to rebuild my GPA, but I managed to get 3.0 GPA in the remaining 4 semesters. Should I write 3.0 as my GPA on the resume or should I write accumulated GPA calculated over the 8 semesters from community college and the university? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if the school to which you are applying has stated a specific way to count things, but it sounds like being 3.4 to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume this is the US. Most places will want the average over the four years, just as if you had switched from one four year program to another.

You can list the two separately if you like, unless you are filling out an online form that only permits one number. But if you need to report a single number you should provide the most honest weighted average you can come up with over the four years.

Normally courses are "weighted" by credit hours or some equivalent. Normally a 4 credit course meets more often than a 3 credit course. The other variable is the "quality points" of a grade.

Complications arise when one school is on a system where an A counts as 4.0 quality points but another uses a different scale, perhaps including A+ which is above A, perhaps 4.5.

But also note that the GPA isn't the only consideration in applying for jobs or for further education. The actual grades in "important" courses might be more important (and often is). There are many other factors that let a committee make a somewhat valid prediction of a person's likelihood of success.

But don't just report the final four semesters without any comment. That will give an incorrect picture, and, in your case, seems to be a disadvantageous one.

Comment: If the transferred credits are not included in the subsequent school's transcript, I would be hesitant to include them in your GPA at that institution. It might appear dishonest because those credits were not earned there.

Comment: @BryanKrause, no, don't imply that they are from an institution to which they don't apply. That is fraud. But an "overall" GPA need imply that all were earned in the same place. Moving between institutions isn't a rare occurrence.